# Word to differentiate the spiciness of chilli pepper and mustard

Tags: single-word-requests

We use the word *hot* or *spicy* to describe the kind of sensation you'd experience with chilli pepper. A burning of the mouth and throat.

But is there a separate word for the kind of sensation you'd experience with mustard or horseradish? The fizzy nasal feeling you get when eating things like this.

E.g. Chilli is hot, mustard is _____, and ginger is both hot and _____.

Comment: Note this isn't a duplicate of hot vs spicy or hot vs hot questions. It is specifically about the sensation of mustard, horseradsih, ginger etc.

Comment: Personally, I would put mustard in the same category as ginger. Chile peppers contain capsaicin, and the "hot" in mustard comes from other chemicals mixed with water. On the other hand, ginger contains chemicals that are closer to capsaicin.

Comment: This page seems relevant: [Why is your tolerance for wasabi different than your tolerance for capsaicin-based flavors in hot sauces and other spicy foods?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-your-tolerance-for-wasabi-different-than-your-tolerance-for-capsaicin-based-flavors-in-hot-sauces-and-other-spicy-foods) Apparently the heat from chilli (capsaicin) primarily hits the *tongue*, whereas the heat from mustard, wasabi, etc. (allyl isothiocyanate) primarily hits the *nasal passages*. So perhaps one might say the latter is more ***pungent***.

Answer (score 7):

The distinctive flavor of horseradish, mustard, or ginger is primarily an olfactory sensation:

> What Does Horseradish Taste Like? The horseradish root possesses a potent flavor, commonly described as hot, spicy and peppery.  Unlike hot peppers that burn the tongue, the intense spice of the horseradish is [*experienced through the nose and sinuses*](https://www.ehow.com/info_12314255_horseradish-taste-like.html).  — Christina Kalinowski, “What Does Horseradish Taste Like?”  eHow.

*Pungent* is the most common descriptive, sometimes *sharp*, with the entire sensation called *bite*.

> The distinctive [*pungent*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseradish#Culinary_uses) taste of horseradish is from the compound allyl isothiocyanate. — Wikipedia
>
> Half spicy and peppery, half lemony, slightly sweet but [*pungent*](https://harvesttotable.com/ginger_half_spicy_and_peppery/): that's how you might describe the flavor of ginger. — “Ginger: Kitchen Basics,” Harvest to Table, 12 April 2007.
>
> There is no flavor in the world quite like that of ginger. It is hot, zesty and biting yet sweet and warm. Ginger is quite [*pungent*](https://www.spiceography.com/ginger/) and spicy with a very slight woody flavor that lends a certain mildness to its overall flavor profile. This particular ingredient is as aromatic as it is flavorful. — Spiceography
>
> Spicy, warm and [*sharp*](http://www.t8nmagazine.com/ginger/) are all words that have been used to describe ginger's taste. — *T8N Magazine*
>
> The [*pungency*](https://www.compoundchem.com/2014/11/27/ginger/) can be attributed to the presence of gingerols; one of the main culprits here is the compound [6](https://www.compoundchem.com/2014/11/27/ginger/)-gingerol. This particularly chemical is not too distant from capsaicin, the compound that gives chillies their spiciness, and piperine, found in black pepper. … Cooking produces zingerone, which is less *pungent*, and is characteristic of the ginger flavour found in gingerbread. It’s less *pungent* than the gingerols, leading to a differing flavour to fresh ginger. 
>   Another class of compounds that can be produced by cooking or drying are the shogaols, which are approximately twice as *pungent* as the gingerols which proceed them. This helps explain why dried ginger has a greater *pungency* than fresh ginger. — “The Chemistry of Ginger – Flavour, Pungency & Medicinal Potential,” CompoundChem.com, 27 Nov. 2014.
>
> What is ground ginger?
>   Taste: [*Pungent*](https://www.thekitchn.com/inside-the-spice-cabinet-ground-ginger-211363)
>   Most Popular Use: Baked goods, spice rubs, meat
>
> Ground ginger, sometimes labeled powdered ginger, is made by simply drying out peeled fresh ginger root, then grinding it to a fine powder. It is pale yellow in color and should have a [*pungent*](https://www.thekitchn.com/inside-the-spice-cabinet-ground-ginger-211363), spicy smell to indicate freshness. Ground ginger has a warm, spicy bite, is a little bit sweet, and is not as strongly flavored as fresh ginger. — Kelli Foster, “Inside the Spice Cabinet: Ground Ginger,” TheKitchn.com.
>
> The magic of mustard's [*pungency*](https://www.seriouseats.com/2014/05/mustard-manual-guide-different-types-mustard-varieties-dijon-brown-spicy-yellow-hot-whole-grain.html) and heat comes from enzymes that convert into mustard oil once the seed is broken. The nasal-clearing burn produced is a natural defense against insects, but when mixed with a liquid, this reaction can be stabilized to varying degrees, resulting in a condiment that can add the right *bite* to complete hot dogs, burgers, sandwiches, and so much more. — Joshua Bousel, “Mustard Manual: Your Guide to Mustard Varieties,” Serious Eats

The word *mustard* has its heat hidden within: it derives from Latin [*mustum ardens*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustard_(condiment)#Etymology), ‘burning [must](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/must)’ the latter being the juice of grapes before fermentation or in its initial stages (cf. Ger *Most*, same meaning). The ground seeds were added to make a condiment.

*Horseradish*, however, doesn’t have a horse because it has a “kick,” but because [*horse*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/horseradish#etymonline_v_14471) was appended to popular plant names to indicate ‘strong, large, coarse’, as in the [*horsemint*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horsemint).

Comment: McGee's *On Food and Cooking: The Science and Lore of the Kitchen* is another excellent reference that collects horseradish, mustard, garlic, black pepper, Sichuan pepper, grains of paradise, and sansho under the classification of pungent.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think a word exists in the English language that can conveys this and you are better off using a new metaphor:

Chili is fire; mustard is gasoline; and ginger is napalm.